# How do I get the value of a dictionary that contains a list of dictionaries in java?

Tags: java

I am working on a programm in Java which contains a part where I get a couple of information from my Python Server. It is a Hashmap that looks like this:

```
{hid=null, art=CWE, produktgruppe=23, objekt=Küche, betrag=714.989990234375, iban=DE0212, id=2812, varten=[{art=2, lz_min=24, lz_max=36, faktor=null, zinssatz=0.5, kondnr=84}], status=979}
```

How can I get the value of the key "zinssatz".

I tried it with

```
mymap.get("zinssatz");
```

But that always returns zero. Which is probably because it can't find the key inside my hashmap because it is build like a "Dictionary with a list of dictionaries" inside it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes I tried this and then I got this result: [{art=2, lz_min=24, lz_max=36, faktor=null, zinssatz=0.5, kondnr=84}]

Comment: Hey, yes I am very new to java. I am learning it atm and thought I could get a quick answer with this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a nested map. Have you tried the following:

```
((HashMap)mymap.get("varten")).get("zinssatz");
```

Or, if you're not sure if `varten` is really a `HashMap`, you can try the following to get the type:

```
System.out.println(mymap.get("varten").getClass());
```

**Update**

If `varten` is a `HashMap` stored inside an `ArrayList`, try the following:

```
((HashMap)((ArrayList)mymap.get("varten")).get(0)).get("zinssatz");
```

...which is the same as:

```
List list = (ArrayList) mymap.get("varten");
Map map = (HashMap) list.get(0);
Object zinssatz = map.get("zinssatz");
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot do that because:
"Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'object' for the second .get

Comment: Then you probably need a cast, I' ve updated my answer.

Comment: It is an ArrayList. That's why I am getting the error ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I know how to access my keys.